# How to add Google API scopes to IdentityServer4

Tags: .net-core, oauth-2.0, openid, identityserver4, google-signin

I am relatively new to the idea of OAuth, OIDC and using IdentityServer4. All I need is 3 components:
1. FrontEnd - Angular
2. Backend - DotNetCore webAPI
3. Authorization/Authentication with Google - IdentityServer4 (I hope so)

Can I use Google Signin with IdentityServer4 and then generate tokens containing info like openID(user info), and containing scopes like 'customWebapi.read' and 'gmail.read' ?

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Please refer to this documentation by Microsoft - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: Only Google can issue tokens that work with its APIs but there's notihg to stop you from allowing users to sign into your product using their Google account.